# Copy to Output Directory in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2017

Hello I am walking through this tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257502/Creating-Your-First-EMGU-Image-Processing-Project).

I have created a Console App project in Visual Studio 2017 and have successfully added references to the EmguCV library. However I am struggling with the OpenCv files.

After adding them to the solution, then highlighting them and clicking properties, there is no available option to "Copy to Output Directory".

[image]

The properties window only displays the Misc section. How do enable "Copy to Output Directory" for these files in VS 2017?

Comment: have you considered post build commands?

Comment: No. Could you provide a reference or more detail?

Comment: Copy to output directory is after a project build, for your project, right-click and go to properties, go to build events tab, then edit post build, and use the command (for example: xcopy $(SolutionDir)\opencv_core2410.dll $(TargetDir)), (note that $(SolutionDir) and $(TargetDir) are macros)

Comment: I also assume that you are using those as a reference, you can right click the reference and change Copy Local to true

Comment: Thx for the response Yaman. Is the TargetDir in this scenario ConsoleOCR and the SolutionDir the folder Solution Items?

Comment: TargetDir is your bin folder of ConsoleOCR and SolutionDir holds solution items and project folders, open the edit post build and click Macros, you can see the equivalent value for those

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solution Items are part of the solution folder structure and do no belong to a project, Copy to Output directory relates to a project build, which copies the items to the output directory on a successful build.

In your case, you want to copy those 2 dlls when you build your ConsoleOCR Project, you can use post build events.

Go to your project, right click and select Properties. Then go to Build Events tab, click Edit Post-Build and specify the commands:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)\opencv_core2410.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)\opencv_imgproc2410.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

I assume you use those DLLs as references in your project, you can go to your References in the project and right click them then change the property of Copy Local to True.

Comment: Right now I am attempting to determine the correct file paths. According to the tutorial the OpenCv items are c++ items and need to be placed in the Solution Folder so unfortunately there is no Copy Local to True. At the moment I have xcopy "$(ConsoleOCR/Solution Items/)\opencv_core2410.dll" "$(ConsoleOCR/bin/)"

Comment: xcopy "$(Solution Items)\opencv_core2410.dll" "$(TargetDir)\"
No need to specify solution name, because it's relative to the current solution

Comment: Check the Output window, it will show you this command and its output

Comment: 2017 update: use robocopy; also if you're still using VS 2012 you don't want the \'s after $(TargetDir) or $(SolutionDir) (there's also a $(ProjectDir)